# Javascript put JSON object values as text for radio buttons or list

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I'm new to web programming and know basically nothing. So if my practices are bad, I'm sorry.

I want to create a simple app that takes JSON objects and retrieves data from them and alters the HTML. What I exactly want to do is:

Get data from a JSON object like this one;
I only want to use vanilla javascript with no external libraries (so I learn) so jQuery for example is out of the question.

```
{
        "id" : 21,
        "question": "What is 2 + 8?",
        "alternatives": {
            "alt1": 2,
            "alt2": 8,
            "alt3": 10,
            "alt4": 28
        },
        "answer" : "alt3"
    }
```

I can get by key for example

```
 var id = jSONobj.id
```

But how can I iterate over the alts in "alternatives" and set the values to my radio buttons:

```
<form action="" id="input4radio">
  <input type="radio" name="ans"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="ans"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="ans"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="ans"><br>
</form>
```

I assume that I use a for-loop but javascript is in my opinion very chaotic compared to java which is what I'm used to. So I don't know how to do such a function. Most answers I've seen either use jQuery or just get the values from the alt-list. They don't put the values anywhere.

Please help!

Comment: Are you creating `DOM` dynamically ?

Comment: Do you control the json you're receiving? Can you make alternatives an array? It's allready indexed

Comment: @Rayon Well yes, My DOM is created "dynamically" I just do .style.display = 'none'; depending on the type of question.

Comment: @Danny – Why so ? You should create your DOM based on `JSON`

Comment: @baoo No, The Json Object I get is unknown but the question either has textbox answer, 3 alternatives or 4 alternatives.

Comment: @Rayon I'm sorry, what do you mean? I change the DOM answer form based on the properties of the JSON object I recieve. So if for example the JSON obj does not contain "alternatives", i present the textbox answerform.

Comment: @Danny — https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ym8nkv3y/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the steps could be:

- On the window onload event call a JS function
- Get the form in DOM by it's ID
- Loop through the 'alternatives' object inside your data
- Create an input node on each iteration
- Set the value of this node to the value of the key
- Then append the new node to the form

  ```
  var data = {
      "id" : 21,
      "question": "What is 2 + 8?",
      "alternatives": {
          "alt1": 2,
          "alt2": 8,
          "alt3": 10,
          "alt4": 28
      },
      "answer" : "alt3"
  }

  function onLoad() {
      var form = document.getElementById('input4radio');
      for (alt in data.alternatives) {
          var newRadio = document.createElement('input'); 
          newRadio.type = 'radio';
          newRadio.value = data.alternatives[alt];
          form.appendChild(newRadio); 
          form.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      }

  }

  window.onload = onLoad;
  ```

And then have an empty form in HTML:

```
    <form action="" id="input4radio">
```

I came from a Java background too - in time I think you'll come to see the chaos as flexibility :)